# Laravel using named routes

Tags: php, laravel

Regarding the use of named routes, these 2 lines allow me to access the same page so which is correct?

```
// Named route
Route::get('test/apples', array('as'=>'apples', 'uses'=>'TestController@getApples'));

// Much simpler
Route::get('apples', 'TestController@getApples');
```

Is there any reason I should be using named routes if the latter is shorter and less prone to errors?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only advantage is it is easier to link to, and you can change the URL without going through and changing all of its references.  For example, with named routes you can do stuff like this:

```
URL::route('apples');
Redirect::route('apples');
Form::open(array('route' => 'apples'));
```

Then, if you update your route, all of your URLs will be updated:

```
// from
Route::get('test/apples', array('as'=>'apples', 'uses'=>'TestController@getApples'));

// to
Route::get('new/apples', array('as'=>'apples', 'uses'=>'TestController@getApples'));
```

Another benefit is logically creating a URL with a lot parameters.  This allows you to be a lot more dynamic with your URL generation, so something like:

```
Route::get('search/{category}/{query}', array(
    'as' => 'search',
    'uses' => 'SearchController@find',
));

$parameters = array(
    'category' => 'articles',
    'query' => 'apples',
);

echo URL::route('search', $parameters);
// http://domain.com/search/articles/apples
```

Comment: If it's a question of links, can't I just do `Redirect::to('apples')` or `Form::open(array('url'=>'apples'))`? It looks like unless I plan on changing my mind on method names in the future then ok use named routes. Then again, that would be a sign of poor class planning.

Comment: @enchance you pretty much hit the head on the nail.  Most of the time it only increases readability (oh, we are routing to the "apples" page; instead of hmm, what is on the "test/apples" URL).  But it also can save a lot of time if you change a URL route.  I also added a good instance of when it would be a lot more logical to used a named route.

Comment: I'm a bit confused...actually more than before I asked. If you're changing the target of the link why not change the route directly since you're obviously keeping the link name? That would be `TestController@getNewmethod`.

Comment: @enhance not the method, but the URL.  So going from `domain.com/test/apples` to `domain.com/new/apples`, you won't have to go through everywhere you reference `href="/test/apples"`..

Answer (score 10):

### Named routes are better, Why ?

It's always better to use a `named route` because insstsead of using the `url` you may use the `name` to refer the route, for example:

```
return Redirect::to('an/url');
```

Now above code will work but if you would use this:

```
return Redirect::route('routename');
```

Then it'll generate the `url` on the fly so, if you even change the `url` your code won't be broken. For example, check your `route`:

```
Route::get('apples', 'TestController@getApples');
Route::get('apples', array('as' => 'apples.show', 'uses' => 'TestController@getApples'));
```

Both routes are same but one without `name` so to use the route without name you have to depend on the `url`, for example:

```
return Redirect::to('apples');
```

But same thing you may do using the route name if your route contains a name, for example:

```
return Redirect::route('apples.show');
```

In this case, you may change the `url` from `apples` to `somethingelse` but still your `Redirect` will work without changing the code.

Comment: Granted it allows you to change urls but how many times does one change a url target for an already live project? It's a link which is a string and not an entire model. Like I mentioned earlier, if you have to change it then you probably should have planned it better.

Answer (score 1):

The only reason to name the route is if you need to reference it later. IE: from your page in a view or something, check whether you are in that route.